# How do I enable the "partner" repository?

Tags: package-management, software-center, software-sources

I keep seeing places refer to the "partner" repository as a place I can get software, how can I enable this repository? Please specify how to do this graphically and via command line.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**GUI Way**:

Click on the ubuntu button, then search for  "Software Sources" (or "Software & Updates" on Ubuntu 16.04+) and go to the "Other Software" tab.

[image]

**Command Line Way**:

- Open the sources.list file: `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` (or with the command line editor of your choice, `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` would use `nano` on the command line without a GUI)
- Add the partner repositories by removing the **#** in front of the following lines (`maverick` is the version of your Ubuntu installation, it may differ, so use the codename of the release you are using instead of 'maverick'. If you're not sure run `lsb_release -c` to find out.)

  ```
  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
  ```

[image: Using GEdit to edit the sources.list file]

- Save and Close.
- Resynchronize the package index files from their sources: `sudo apt-get update`
- [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding%20Canonical%20Partner%20Repositories) for reference

Comment: As of Ubuntu Precise, "Software Sources" is no longer accessible via the launcher. It has to be accessed through the menu (*Edit* => *Edit software sources*).

Comment: @Sid I think you're double dipping here. Your method for the GUI may make more sense, but your method for the command line is dated and the contribution by [Hieu](http://askubuntu.com/a/598307/29097) is better advice. Would you have an object to reducing this method to just the GUI method described? I don't want to downvote you for the GUI contribution. But, I do want to downvote the inferior CLI method (which isn't even really cli because you're using gedit).

Comment: Downvoted because @ThomasWard decided to rollback the edit, and the CLI instructions are inferior and dated. Shouldn't have combined the two.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The instructions are not necessarily inferior - the methods specified here still work, replacing "maverick" with whichever codename is relevant.  You're right the GUI way to edit the CLI version is wrong - note my edits which I made indicating to use a text editor instead for the command line rather than the GUI (such as 'nano').

Comment: @EvanCarroll There's this thing called *updating* via editing. It works quite well :)

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way to enable "partner" repository:

```
sudo sed -i.bak "/^# deb .*partner/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: this doesn't work with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12):

### CLI method

This method uses

- `lsb_release -sc` to get the Ubuntu (codename) version.
- `add-apt-repository` to alter the appropriate config files.

It has the advantages of working in all versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

This is from [a skype tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)

Comment: Brilliant. I'll use this from now on.

Comment: Beware that you can run this command only once. If you do it again, you will have the problem with duplivate entries.

Answer (score 5):

To enable the partner repository from the command line, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`:
`sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`  and remove the **#** from the beginning of these two lines:

```
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner  
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

So they are like this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner  
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

Then update your apt cache: `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 2):

TERMINAL version, just copy and paste this commands to activate the partners repository (skype, etc):

```
DISTRO=`cat /etc/*-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | sed 's/.*=//g'`
sudo sed -i 's/\(# \)\(deb .*ubuntu '${DISTRO}' partner\)/\2/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get -y update
```

@ERGuille: FTFY, with a cleaner version

Comment: Parsing the configuration file is a horrible idea.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with parsing the `sources.list` file. Advisable to make a backup though (use `sed -i.bak` instead of just `sed -i`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it within shell, I took the time for a little variation to increase stability, re-usability and idempotence (and not checking for the distro):

```
grep -qe '^# deb[- ].* partner$' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && sudo sed -i"~$(date -%s)" 's/^# \(deb[- ].* parnter$\)/\1/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

- grep check: change file only if it is to change.
- sed backup: keep timestamp'ed backups so you can go back in time.
- handle both source and non-source.
- use the name (last field) not the distro to identify the repositories.

Alternatives here:

- If you don't care about source and want to keep no backups: https://askubuntu.com/a/51244/55951
- If you prefer something more complicated looking of which is told it would extract the distro name and you don't care about source and you want to overwrite backups: https://askubuntu.com/a/46389/55951
- Even more complicated looking which was said about it was the less cleaner version of the previous one: https://askubuntu.com/a/37203/55951
- Interesting approach to add into a new file of it's own: https://askubuntu.com/a/471539/55951

In the end this might need another iteration or two. I hope next to the personal note on comments this was giving some useful summary.

Answer (score -1):

TERMINAL
just to make it easier,
copy and paste this one command:

`sed 's/\# deb http\:\/\/archive\.canonical\.com\/ubuntu natty partner/deb http\:\/\/archive\.canonical\.com\/ubuntu natty partner/' /etc/apt/sources.list | sed 's/\# deb-src http\:\/\/archive\.canonical\.com\/ubuntu natty partner/deb-src http\:\/\/archive\.canonical\.com\/ubuntu natty partner/' - > /tmp/newfile && sudo mv -f /tmp/newfile /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: There are *way* easier and more elegant one-liners you could come up with.  `sed -i~ 's|^# *\(deb\(-src\)* http://archive\.canonical\.com/ubuntu natty partner|\1|' /etc/apt/sources.list` uses a single regular expression, but creating a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` would be much better still.