# Firefox Hangs on ubuntu when loading java applets

Tags: firefox, openjdk

I am using Firefox 3.6.12 on ubuntu 10.10 amd64 with Openjdk JRE. Firefox seems to hang for a long time when loading applets from websites using java. Things seem to work smoothly on Windows. I have the same problem with Firefox 4.0 b8. is this a bug with openjdk,firefox or ubuntu? Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the official Sun (Oracle) Java client, instead of the OpenJDK one.  To do so, run synaptic from System/Administration/Synaptic, then click on Settings/Repositories, then [choose the "Other Software" tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository).  Now put a tick next to "Canonical Partners" and okay that and reload your packages.

Now search for "JRE".  Remove the "openjdk" packages, and select the "sun-java6" packages.  When you hit apply, you'll be told that you'll be removing "default-jre", but don't worry about that as you've already manually added what you want.

Give your package another go and see if it performs any differently.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry tinhed but it is not a problem with Firefox, or at least complete to firefox (I wish it were related to the browser). The problem is how the java applet is made. I know you have tested other places and the applet in those places works great, but in others it does not. Same for flash. Some flash sites can kill the browser, while others do not. If you can provide the java site i can help further down the problem. Maybe download google chrome and opera just to test out.

Hope i can be of assitance with this annoying problem.