# Skype fails to start after installation from downloaded deb package

Tags: 64-bit, skype

i installed skype wiht the amd64.deb file that i downloaded from skype.com
but when i click it via dash it wont start.
after that i tried it from the gnome-terminal i get this
 
i have a dutch Ubuntu i translated it(well i hope)

> bash: /usr/bin/skype:File or directory does not exist

i remove it using `sudo apt-get remove` 
i then installed it again using

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_amd64.deb
```

but again same problem

i checked in the /usr/bin there is a skype file
and the permissions where -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21362968 2011-06-08

Comment: can you do a ls -la /usr/bin/skype ? Do you have execute permissions? I have skype up and working on my amd64 system.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21362968 2011-06-08 12:26 /usr/bin/skype i am not familiar with those -rwxr-xr-x  commands.

Comment: @blade19899 Please edit info into the question itself, do not respond via comments, thanks

Comment: @blade19899 check 32 bit , will work ok

Comment: i got skype up and running i installed a while ago super-os-repo-0.4.004.deb which has a skype*.deb in its repository i deleted it and super-os-repo-0.4.004.deb and run  sudo apt-get update/upgrade/autoremove/check/autoclean/clean/ and so on then i installed skype from the official repository and no problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is in fact a 32-bit program even if it's packaged for 64-bit. When downloading Skype from skype.com, you won't install the necessary 32-bit compatibility libraries on Ubuntu Oneiric. The error is a bit misleading, but it means that 32-bit compatibility libraries are not installed on a 64-bit machine.

The recommended method to install Skype is throught the Partner repository.

1. Uninstall the Skype package using the Software Center. If you cannot find it, [open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge skype
   ```
2. [Enable the partner repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/14629/6969)
3. Refresh the packages information and install Skype from the Software Center (package "skype")

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me file's executable bit's are set, even then, set the execution permission something like sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/skype 
Or alternatively why don't you try it installing from Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic?
this way Ubuntu will install a compatible version on your machine, and as @one-zero said try installing 32 bit.

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center doesn't have 64 bit version mean there is something ...

Comment: I meant check that executable bits are set

Comment: The correct way to *add* the executable bit is with `chmod +x file`. That respects the [umask](http://askubuntu.com/q/44542/6969) and does not unnecessary add write permissions which can lead to an [insecure system](http://askubuntu.com/q/20105/6969)

Comment: The CORRECT way to make sure this instruction works is "chmod 500" or "chmod 755" or some variation thereof (chmod 777 is too permissive). If the umask is incorrect (0333, 0377 etc), then chmod +x will not solve the problem.