# Why is the Purchase Section in Software Center empty?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

The "For Purchase" section in the USC is empty.

Why?

Comment: @Rinzwind "All Software"->"For Purchase"

Answer (score 2):

So now it works!

What I did:

1. Open software center, go to "Edit->Software Sources"
2. Disable "Canonical Partner" checkbox
3. Enable "Canonical Partner" checkbox again
4. Wait some seconds and restart USC

More info:

- [How do I enable the "partner" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure under the `View` menu you have `All Software` ticked and not just `Canonical-Maintained Software`.