# What Linux program reads Atrac3+?

Tags: software-recommendation, music-player

I have about 20 files of music in the format .aa3. Which Linux-compatible program reads that format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First enable *restricted*, [*multiverse*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) and [*partner*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository) repository. [Click here to see a bunch of helpful questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20repository) about how to do this. By default restricted repository is enabled.

Open a terminal and execute this command to install necessary codecs to play `.aa3` format files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
```

Then you can open and play files with standard player. Such as Rhythmbox or totem.

#### OP says the method doesn't work.

If this method doesn't work, I guess the files are DRM protected. In simple words, DRM protection is used to prevent piracy of Digital contents (there are other usages also) such as Music, Videos etc. You need a key to decrypt or read the digital content which is only supplied to you by the Vendor.

Check these Links to know more about DRM protection:

- [Digital Right Management (DRM) - Wikipedia Article](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20repository)
- [How DRM works - How Stuff works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/drm.htm)
- [DRM and Music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management#DRM_and_music)

Comment: Please take note that, If your files are DRM protected, you may have some problem playing them

Comment: it gives an error saying:
Unable to locate package gstreame10-plugins-ugly

Comment: @NickyBailuc see my updated answer. You have to first enable repositories and unfortunately there was an typo in code. Now fixed. thanks

Comment: "nul - Couldn't start playback"
gives an error

Comment: How did you try to paly. Try with Totem player

Comment: totem says "error, could not read type of stream"

Comment: @NickyBailuc Make sure your music files are not DRM protected. In that case, you need the keys to play them

Comment: whats drm protected

Comment: also if helps, i got this from a psp game called metal slug, the umd allowed me to download it directly to my memory stick and the psp was able to play those soundtracks

Comment: @NickyBailuc Then i'm 85% sure that it is DRP protected and can only be played in psp.

Comment: that sucks, well thanks for taking your time to explain, i really appreciate it