# Missing Canonical partners and independent repositories in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: repository, canonical

I have encountered a strange problem today when I found that Canonical partners and independent repositories have gone missing from "other software" tab of "software and updates".
I also noticed that "main", "universe", "multiverse" and "restricted" are all disabled as well as "trusy-security", "trusty-updates", "trusy-proposed" and "trusty-backports".

The question is : how can I add Canonical and independent repositories back so that I can re-enable them ? and what could have caused this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Partner and Extra repositories seem to be missing from all repository servers...for 12.04 and 14.04. Are they just gone?

Comment: I don't know...may be an update did this..

However the solution below fixed it and all are working fine...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "partner" repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Replace all the text with this:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Save, close gedit, then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Wow that was quick...thank you but I have another question : if I replace all the text in /etc/apt/sources.list , wouldn't that affect other PPas Ithat I have added ?

Comment: @AsadAlrafidain If you added PPAs using `apt-add-repository` they are stored in individual `.list` files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. The file `sources.list` is not the recommended place for PPAs. Backup the original text so you can restore it if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick reply....

actually I added the PPAs using Y-PPA manager so I don't know where it stored the PPAs...anyway I'll do as you said and backup the original file.

Thanks for your kindness...by the way, I wanted to mark your answer as useful but I don't have enough reputation to do that :p

Comment: -1 Replace all with. How bad is that suggestion? I can't see you keep your answer here up-to-the-date to make such broad suggestions. I would have loved to see you make the description what you actually changed, how you did it and why you did it - then provide the example of how it looked afterwards on your system at that place in time and space.