# Unable to update my ubuntu server 14.04 using apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

I am unable to update my ubuntu server 14.04 using `apt-get update`.

Outcome is:

```
W: failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/inrelease
```

And another error is:

```
/usr/local/snort/bin/snort: error while loading shared libraries: libdnet.1 : cannot open shared object
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Was this a fresh install of 14.04 or an upgrade? Can you post the output of *grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list*

Comment: Something is wrong with your sources.list - restore it by following the answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/459542/missing-canonical-partners-and-independent-repositories-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

  
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

Comment: What happens if you follow the answer on http://askubuntu.com/questions/128369/sudo-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu-12-04 (do "select best server" in Software Sources)? And when you run `apt-get update`, before the "Failed to fetch" errors are there any lines that begin with "Err http://"?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue. My company has a firewall that stopped apt-get from getting to the http sources. They still allow ftp traffic, so I was able to work around the firewall by changing all the "http" sites in sources.list to "ftp". For example, in file /etc/apt/sources.list, I changed line:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
```

to

```
deb ftp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
```

Now apt-get is able to fetch the files from the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

edit  /etc/resolve.conf  file and change nameserver adress e.g 8.8.8.8 if thats not solving your problem  try this [tutorial](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/)

Comment: Some ISP disallow the usage of google's nameserver 8.8.8.8 which might be you in further trouble. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

You should try `sudo apt-get upgrade` that will run as superuser and upgrade you to 16.04 if you dont want that try `sudo apt-get update` to run the command as superuser thats what u usually do if your updating your current version there also could be no new updated versions but I bet there are if you want to check you can use sudo apt-get dist-upgrade to upgrade your current verison of ubuntu like 14.04 to 14.14 for expmple though ther might not be a 14.14 version of ubuntu!!! Thank you for the question!