# Ubuntu 14.04, problem installing package skype: i386

Tags: wireless, skype

I have some problems with my Ubuntu 14.04. I can get both wireless and wired Internet with it. It is also very slow to start. When I performed any actions like update, upgrade or install, it will show me this message.

```
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package skype:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I solve those issues?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get Internet with both wireless and wired network

Comment: It's not clear to me if you have an Internet connection or not. Please clarify the question, and show exactly which commands you run and the resulting output.

Comment: Yes I can get internet connection, but using wired network. But if I want to install any other package or updating my system, it will show me that message about "package skype:i386" needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. And that operation, installing another package stops.

Comment: Show the content of /etc/apt/sources.list file

Comment: Here are the contents of /etc/apt/sources.listd

Comment: Here are the contents of /etc/apt/sources.listd    canonical_partner.list       google-chrome.list
canonical_partner.list.save  google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
dropbox.list                 google-chrome.list.save
dropbox.list.distUpgrade     nhandler-ppa-trusty.list
dropbox.list.save            nhandler-ppa-trusty.list.save

Answer (score 2):

here's the solution that worked for me, I had the same problem,

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq skype
```

If you have any broken package, just replace skype with the name of the package.
Try that and let me know if that helped you.

Comment: just copy and paste-
" dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq skype "
in the terminal and hit enter and problem solved, :)

Answer (score 0):

If apt-get can't find the skype package, the Canonical Partner repository is probably not enabled. I suggest that you [enable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository) and try again.

Comment: How to enable skype package? Because I can't even open my Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: How to enable Canonical Partner repository? Because I can't even open my Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: @coulou: Can you please open a terminal window, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and show us **all** the resulting output? (Edit your question and post it there; don't post it as a comment.)

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade gives me that: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package skype:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: @coulou: Try removing the skype package: `sudo apt-get purge skype` and then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: it doen't work. update is showing : Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                          
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                           
  404  Not Found

Comment: @coulou: Ignore those errors for now. Did you run all the commands I asked you to run?