# What are the old-release alternatives for http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I'm trying to upgrade my system from Ubuntu 11.04 to the latest supported version. As usually when dealing with linux, I'm having a [lot of fun](https://askubuntu.com/q/511355/128031). I have found a [answer that suggests to re-map the software sources](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/128031) to a different location.

After re-maping, some entries remained unchanged and are now causing problems:

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
```

I need to re-map them too. This is what I see when upgrading before the upgrade fails:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So where is *old-release* version of this server?

Answer (score 1):

They don't exist. Just remove those lines, do a `sudo apt-get update`, and then continue with the upgrade.

When it's finished you can then re-add the partner repository:

- [How do I enable the "partner" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)