# Can't install Skype or update in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 15.04, kde, skype

I am rather new to Linux, so I figured I would start "easy" with Kubuntu. My issue was immediate that Skype would not install. It is not in Muon Discover (software center) and adding the repo to install via Konsole does not work.

So, here is the error I get:

```
    tyler@tyler-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
    Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package skype:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'skype:i386' has no installation candidate
```

I have also just tried downloading the .deb file and installing it via Konsole with no luck.

Though perhaps an even larger issue is that when I try to enter "sudo apt-get update" I get the following error:

```
tyler@tyler-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So what is with this? I have modified the source.list file numerous times. Here is the current format:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the partner repository

- [How do I enable the "partner" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)

Then update index by `sudo apt-get update` and use `sudo apt-get install skype` to install it.

The partner repository for main server in Trusty is like this one

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

You should change the `trusty` with `vivid` or your specific release name.

Comment: I don't have partner repos. Can you list the ones for Vivid?

Comment: @TylerStorey see the edit

Comment: for your us server, it should be `deb http://us.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner`

Comment: I added both:
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner  
AND deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner

Comment: Now I get:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Try using main server by removing the `us.` part from server address.

Comment: Just a warning to the future -- the `archive.canonical.com` is completely different from the `archive.ubuntu.com`. Don't confuse the two.