# Can't execute this file

Tags: bash, permissions, skype, ls, execute-command

I can't execute the skype file.
I have the permissions I need. What's the meaning of `filename*` in the `ll` output?

[image: ls and execution output]

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `file skype` and `uname -a`.

Comment: Haven't you forgot the `*`, as in skype*?

Comment: The `*` in this context is the `ls` command's way of indicating an executable file - you're seeing it because `ll` is an alias for `ls` that includes the `-F` option. See `man ls`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should use the packaged version of Skype. Just enable the Canonical partners repositories in Software Sources ([How do I enable the "partner" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)), click Close, then update the list. After this you will be able to install Skype from Ubuntu Software Center, and it will run properly.